# How to archive files from specific folder, which is present in a particular drive to another folder using .bat file

Tags: batch-file

How to archive files from specific folder, which is present in a particular drive to another folder on same drive or to different drive using .bat file.

i.e Folder A Contains folders A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I.....(Folder is in share drive has been mapped has A: drive on my system) now i need to archive (probably .zip)  Content of the A i.e A:\A should be archive under path C:\A and then content of the C i.e A:\C should be archive under path c:\C and then content of the G i.e A:\G should be archive under path c:\G and no need to archive rest of the folders.

Note : files in sub-folder(A,C,G) of A drive to be archive in the C: drive on specific folder i.e A,C,G respectively. i am using WinZip

Comment: Are you using pkzip/zip/7-zip/winzip to archive the folders?  Your question needs some clarifying further - C:\A is a folder or a file?  It doesn't seem to be a .ZIP file

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Comment: For a start, can you write a batch file that just calls WinZIP to archive a folder specified by a hard-coded path? Can you then replace the path with a parameter reference so that you can specify the path as an argument? Can you expand that further by introducing a loop to iterate over an arbitrary number of arguments (paths in the command line) and call WinZIP for them? Please start writing the script yourself and improve it bit by bit till you've reached your goal or hit a problem implementing something. In the latter case, please feel free to come here and ask about that specific problem.